# Blender Randomly colsing with EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

Tags: rendering, error

When I use Blender it randomly closes without any error message.

I tried to open it via cmd and I noticed it always crashes with the error EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION

There's no specific situation when it happens (mostly while rendering, in every version), but it happens really frequently and it's becoming very annoying, I can't even render a single scene.

All graphics drivers are up to date, these are my specs:
CPU: Intel Core i7 6700HQ
RAM: 16GB
GPUs: Intel HD Graphics 530 / NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M (Blender is set to use this last one)

Comment: Might it be that your processor is overclocked a lot? Or maybe RAM?

Comment: Nope, I'm on a laptop, never done any overclocking whatsoever

Comment: I'm having this problem on my laptop as well. I've tried a bunch of solutions I googled but none of them have worked. Not sure what to try next.

Comment: I've already reported the bug, but they say it's somewhat related to my hardware. Anyway, I think it's not so uncommon